# SQL select overlap rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, overlap

I got this table operation:

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------+
| theatreNo |    startDateTime    | duration |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+
|         1 | 2019-05-12 09:30:00 | 04:50:00 |
|         3 | 2019-05-17 15:05:00 | 02:00:00 |
|         3 | 2019-05-17 16:05:00 | 03:00:00 |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+
```

And I'm trying to find if we have a theatre where two operations are overlapping and it should output this:

```
+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
| roomNo | startDateTime | firstOp  | secondOp |
+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
|      3 | 2019-05-17    | 15:05:00 | 16:05:00 |
+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
```

It is overlapped because one operation starts at 15:05 and has a duration of 2h and another one in the same theatre starts at 16:05 but the first operation did not finish yet.

I don't know if there is some kind of way where you can calculate the difference between the start time and duration and compare it to the next operations' start time.

Comment: You can use [ADDTIME()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_addtime.asp) and `JOIN`

Comment: I think it would be useful to have a surrogate key: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rPCAjoDQ79hpjQCzDzyW2P/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ADDTIME()` find [manual here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime).
In the manual you will also find `DATE()` and `TIME()`

```
SELECT o1.theatreNo as roomNo,
       DATE(o1.startDateTime) as startDateTime, 
       TIME(o1.startDateTime) as firstOp, 
       TIME(o2.startDateTime) as secondOp
FROM operation o1
JOIN operation o2 ON o1.theatreNo = o2.theatreNo
WHERE o1.startDateTime < ADDTIME(o2.startDateTime,o2.duration)
AND ADDTIME(o1.startDateTime,o1.duration) > o2.startDateTime
AND o1.startDateTime < o2.startDateTime;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cfrhWey8oVKGK83XELJCsb/14)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` to get pairs of overlaps in the same row:

```
select o.*, o2.*
from operation o join
     operation o2
     on o2.theatreNo = o.theatreNo and
        o2.startDateTime < o.startDateTime + o.duration and
        o2.startDateTime + o2.duration > o.startDateTime and
        (o2.startDateTime <> o.startDateTime or
         o2.duration <> o.duration
        );
```

The logic gets much harder if you want to summarize the overlaps.  The issue is that multiple time periods could overlap.  You can get any pair in the same row -- but that pair might overlap with another, so there would be redundancy.

Comment: This query doesn't work in my demo. Changing the last lines with `o2.startDateTime + o2.duration > o.startDateTime AND o2.startDateTime < o.startDateTime;` and it's work

Comment: @AlbertoMoro . . . That is not the exact logic.  I fixed the query.

Answer (score 1):

There can be N number of overlaps.

So if you are expecting that we can create some query on the same considering the probability of N number of possibilities where 0<=N<=M (N = number of overlaps, M = number of cases), then the result will show the same "roomNo" or "theatreNo" multiple times for the input case given below.

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------+
| theatreNo |    startDateTime    | duration |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+
|         1 | 2019-05-12 09:30:00 | 04:50:00 |
|         3 | 2019-05-17 15:05:00 | 02:00:00 |
|         3 | 2019-05-17 16:05:00 | 03:00:00 |
|         3 | 2019-05-17 17:05:00 | 03:00:00 |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+
```

It will give the following answer

```
+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
| roomNo | startDateTime | firstOp  | secondOp |
+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
|      3 | 2019-05-17    | 15:05:00 | 16:05:00 |
|      3 | 2019-05-17    | 16:05:00 | 17:05:00 |
+--------+---------------+----------+----------+
```

To avoid this you can use the following query which is showing all the overlaps

```
SELECT o1.theatreNo as roomNo,
       DATE(o1.startDateTime) as startDateTime, 
       TIME(o1.startDateTime) as firstOp, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(o2.startDateTime)) as allOp
FROM operation o1
JOIN operation o2 ON o1.theatreNo = o2.theatreNo
WHERE o1.startDateTime < ADDTIME(o2.startDateTime,o2.duration)
AND ADDTIME(o1.startDateTime,o1.duration) > o2.startDateTime
AND o1.startDateTime < o2.startDateTime;
```

Which will give you the following result

```
+--------+---------------+----------+--------------------+
| roomNo | startDateTime | firstOp  | allOp              |
+--------+---------------+----------+--------------------+
|      3 | 2019-05-17    | 15:05:00 | 16:05:00, 17:05:00 |
+--------+---------------+----------+--------------------+
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cfrhWey8oVKGK83XELJCsb/15)